# Catching Twilio API exceptions- PHP

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am using Twilio to send SMS to users. On an invalid number, I am getting 400. How can I catch that exception or HTTP Status code so that I can handle it accordingly? It does return [these](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/v1/error-codes) codes and I want to know the HTTP Code received in the API response.

```
 $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
 $client->messages->create(
          $to, array(
            'body' => $message,
            'from' =>$SMS_FROM
             )
 );
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting thee `$client` object in the debugger? I havent used this API personally, but Id expect that info to be in that object somewhere.

Comment: @WesleySmith tried `  print_r($client);die;` right after the call but the exception is thrown before that, by `create` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just wrap the code block in a try/catch block, as in this example?

```
try {
    $twilio
        ->messages
        ->create(
            $to,
            [
                'body' => "Here is my message to you!",
                'from' => $SMS_FROM,
            ]
        );
} catch (\Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException $e) {
    echo "Something went wrong.\nCode: {$e->getCode()}.\nMessage: {$e->getMessage()}.\n";
}
```

This will print out the full error message which should give you what you want, e.g.:

> [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'From' number +12132635abc137
> is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender ID.

Comment: That's right, that's how I had resolved it, came across the details of TwilioException and I used it in that way.